# Localizable strings for each Target

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, target

I have a Xcode project in Swift 3. For each Storyboard, I have localized strings in english and spanish. I have multiple Targets in the project and I need different text in the labels for each Target in the Storyboards. For example, in the storyboard called Restaurants, the title label element show "Name" in Target01 but in Target02, must be say "Restaurant Name".

Thank you for the help.